# 'Restore Packages' option is missing on right click in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to start with Angular 2 and Visual Studio 2015 (Update 3) eq. with this tutorial: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html
i need to "restore packages" on right click on 'packages.json'-file, but this option is missing in menu.

Any hints?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?  I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 13):

If you like, you can restore your packages using the `npm` command. This is same as doing the restore package. Hope it helps.

1. open up the command prompt
2. cd into the folder where you have your angular project
3. run this command : `npm install`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem but restarting vs worked.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have saved the solution while restoring packages, I saved the files and it works for me